# CKEditor 5 asks to set <div> instead of <textarea>, but @Model.Class.Value always = null

Tags: javascript, c#, .net-core, ckeditor

I am trying to create a text input field for a client based on CKEditor 5.

This is not a classic CKEditor. The classic one just needs to specify  and everything works:

```
<textarea id="editor_middle_en" asp-for="ProjectProduct.MiddleDescription_en">@Html.Raw(Model.ProjectProduct.MiddleDescription_en)</textarea>
```

But the custom CKEditor requires me to put not `<textarea>`, `<div>`:

```
<div id="editor_middle_en" asp-for="ProjectProduct.MiddleDescription_en">@Html.Raw(Model.ProjectProduct.MiddleDescription_en)</div>
```

asp-for with  always sends me null in @Model.Project Product.MiddleDescription_en in the controller method, which I call using submit:

```
<input id="submit" class="btn btn-info" hidden type="submit" value="submit"/>

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Method(Model? model) {
    model.ProjectProduct.MiddleDescription_en = null; !!!
}
```

How do I transfer the actual text from CKEditor 5 ? I tried doing hidden input - it works, but it's a separate block and the text doesn't change there. I also tried to pick up the actual text from  using oninput=Method(this);", but in the console I see an error like domconverter-unsafe-attribute-detected.

Thanks!